# How do I set my tomcat with a verified Cert?

Tags: ssl, certificate, tomcat7

I am trying to set my tomcat with SSL. I have finished it. But, when I surf on my server the SSL certificate is not trusted.
I imported into my .keystore file a Certificate of one entity, but the result is the same.
This is what i want:

[image]

This is what i got
[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a certificate that is **accepted** by browsers and clients "automatically", without adding an anchor to the truststore, you must get a certificate issued by one of the established [Certificate Authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Providers) that is builtin to the browser(s) and/or other client program(s) you use. (Note the CA portion of Verisign is now owned by and operates under the name of Symtanec, which also owns Thawte and Geotrust but they still operate under their prior names.)

No trusted CA will issue you a cert for the name "localhost", only for a publicly resolvable and reachable domain name that you own, so if you don't have a domain name you'll have to get that first. Some suppliers, like GoDaddy, do both DNS and certificates (and other things like hosting); you may or may not prefer a single supplier. (Or you may be able get a cert for a static public address, but that's harder to get and harder for people to use.)

If you want the **green bar** in browsers, that requires [Extended Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) which costs more, typically USD 300 and up, and you must prove your legal identity and status by government records. To do this in practice you must be a business, registered and licensed as appropriate for your location.